# event object not reflecting date properly in moment JS

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to update full calendar on event drop event. when i try to console the event it is showing updated time in the start moment(first object in the image). But when i tried to access the start moment by using event.start it is displaying the previous value (below object in image).
how can i get the updated start moment by using event object in the full calendar.
configuration of the fullcalendar

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        height: 780,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            today: 'Hello',
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'Today'
        },
        allDaySlot: false,
        start: moment(),
        end: moment(moment().add(30, 'day')),
        firstDay: (new Date().getDay()),
        timezone: "local",
        defaultView: "agendaWeek",
        eventClick: $scope.onEventClick,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
        eventDragStop: $scope.onDragStop,
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotLabelInterval: "01:00",
    }
```

On Drag Event Function

```
$scope.onDragStop = function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(slot.start);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide us some code instead of image.

Comment: Added now could you please help

Comment: Hello!

why dont you init the Drag Event function in the calendar constructor?
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDragStop/

Comment: @LakiGeri `eventDragStop: $scope.onDragStop` would seem to do that, don't you think?

Comment: Maybe thats the problem, I dont know, but if I have this problem, I'll give it a chance

Comment: @Salesman docs for eventDragStop (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDragStop/) clearly state: "It is triggered before the event's information has been modified (if moved to a new date/time)". If you want to get the altered time, I think you can use eventDrop instead: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/

Comment: @ADyson It worked. Thanks